# How to Create "identical" SpriteNodes that hold the same methods?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm super new to coding (like I started yesterday new). I'm trying to make the same SpriteNode appear multiple times that follow the same methods. For example, the game starts off with one Node that reacts to touch and after you reach 5 points another appears, after 15 another and so on... I have been able to spawn a spriteCopy at 5 points; however I cannot get it to respond to touch like the original node. I'm sure it's something super simple I just don't have the experience. Thanks.

Here is my code so far:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
var sprite: SKSpriteNode!
var touchPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint()
var touching: Bool = false
var score: Int = 0
let scoreTextNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Helvetica Neue UltraLight")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "PongBall")
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: 500,y: 500)
    sprite.size = CGSize(width: 75, height: 75)
    sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 37.5)
    self.addChild(sprite)

    scoreTextNode.text = "\(score)"
    scoreTextNode.fontSize = 70
    scoreTextNode.fontColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    scoreTextNode.position = CGPoint (x: 680.734, y: 700.941)
    self.addChild(scoreTextNode)
}



override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first as UITouch!
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    if sprite.frame.contains(location) {
        touchPoint = location
        touching = true
    }

    if touchPoint == location {
        self.score += 1
        self.scoreTextNode.text = "\(score)"
    }

    let spriteCopy = sprite.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
    if score == 5 {
        self.addChild(spriteCopy)
    }
}


override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first as UITouch!
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    touchPoint = location


}
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    touching = false
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if touching {
        let dt:CGFloat = 1.0/30.0
        let distance = CGVector(dx: touchPoint.x-sprite.position.x, dy: touchPoint.y-sprite.position.y)
        let velocity = CGVector(dx: distance.dx/dt, dy: distance.dy/dt)
        sprite.physicsBody!.velocity=velocity
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Try setting `sprite = spriteCopy` inside the `if score == 5`.

Comment: @Caleb that wont do him any good

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you have multiple sprites appearing on your screen, but you do not do anything with them.  To keep things real simple for you, take this approach.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
  var sprite: SKSpriteNode!
  var touchPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint()
  var touching: Bool = false
  var score: Int = 0
  let scoreTextNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Helvetica Neue UltraLight")
  var spriteList = [SKSpriteNode]() //Add this line

  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "PongBall")
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: 500,y: 500)
    sprite.size = CGSize(width: 75, height: 75)
    sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 37.5)
    self.addChild(sprite)
    spriteList.append(sprite)  //Add This line
    scoreTextNode.text = "\(score)"
    scoreTextNode.fontSize = 70
    scoreTextNode.fontColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    scoreTextNode.position = CGPoint (x: 680.734, y: 700.941)
    self.addChild(scoreTextNode)
  } 



   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

     let touch = touches.first as UITouch!
     let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
     for sprite in spriteList{ //Add This line
         if sprite.frame.contains(location) {
           touchPoint = location
           touching = true
         }

         if touchPoint == location {
            self.score += 1
            self.scoreTextNode.text = "\(score)"
         } 

         let spriteCopy = sprite.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
         if score == 5 {
           self.addChild(spriteCopy)
           spriteList.append(spriteCopy)  //Add this line
         }
       } //Add this line
   }


   override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

     let touch = touches.first as UITouch!
     let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
     touchPoint = location
   }
   override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
     touching = false
   }

   override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

     if touching {
       for sprite in spriteList{ //Add this line
         let dt:CGFloat = 1.0/30.0
         let distance = CGVector(dx: touchPoint.x-sprite.position.x, dy: touchPoint.y-sprite.position.y)
         let velocity = CGVector(dx: distance.dx/dt, dy: distance.dy/dt)
         sprite.physicsBody!.velocity=velocity
       } //Add this line
     }
   }
 }
```

The basic concept is you maintain it in an array.  This should be a good starting point for a beginner.  After you learn how to override classes, you can learn that the touch code can be done inside of the sprite instead of inside of the scene. This would actually be my preferred method.

Comment: @KnightOfDragon You have one tiny mistake. let spriteList = [SKSpriteNode]() will create an immutable array. An array must be mutable in order to add/remove items to it.

Comment: @Whirlwind Yes, you are right, I will fix it,  just a force of habit to use let over var